# integrate sed into find xargs copy shell command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find, xargs

I have a script that I use to copy all of the files in one folder and move them to a new folder... the line i use to do it looks like this

```
find "$SOURCEFOLDER" -type f | xargs -I {} ln {} "$ENDFOLDER/$TR_NEW_TORRENT_NAME/${basename}"
```

and it works perfectly

the thing is I'd like to also use sed to remove any brackets from the basename of the new file but i don't know how to incorporate the sed command

```
sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' FILE
```

how would I go about doing this? Is there a better or simpler way to do all the things I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe following will work for you:

`find "$SOURCEFOLDER" -type f -exec bash -c  "sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {} ; xargs -I {} ln {} "$ENDFOLDER/$TR_NEW_TORRENT_NAME/${basename}" \;`

Idea is to combine the commands this ways:

another way is to use two `-exec`

```
find "$SOURCEFOLDER" -type f -exec sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {}\; -exec ln {} "$ENDFOLDER/$TR_NEW_TORRENT_NAME/${basename}" \;
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Does this remove the brackets from the basename? im sorry i wasn't specific enough

Comment: @MattZera I thought the sed you have given `sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' FILE` does the intended work for you, just the integration in find is a problem. So i used the same sed given by you.

Comment: yes you're correct... it does the work... but does it do it on the whole file with the directory or just the basename

Comment: Neither of these operate on the file name.  Why is this answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-execdir` option of `find` for this renaming and avoid `xargs` altogether:

```
find "$SOURCEFOLDER" -type f -execdir bash -c 'sed "s/\[[^][]*\]//g" <<< "$1";
    ln "$1" "$ENDFOLDER/$TR_NEW_TORRENT_NAME/${basename}"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: This will rename the original file, then pass the original name to the `ln` part, hence an error since this original file has already been renamed. Also, the OP doesn't want to rename the original file.

Comment: OP wrote `I'd like to also use sed to remove any brackets from the basename of the new file` which to my interpretation: OP is trying to rename original file first. (I may be wrong though)

Comment: Newfile ≠ Original file. He wants to remove the brackets of the newfile. And I can conceive that he doesn't want to touch the original file so as to not confuse the torrent client. — Also your command is an error. If there's a file named `a[b]`, then it is _first_ renamed to `a` and _then_ `find` sends _the original file name`, i.e., `a[b]` to be linked with the `ln` command; but at this time, the file `a[b]` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Yes I realized and fixed 2nd part. Will need some clarification from OP on first point though.

Comment: Right `;)`. You need to quote `$1` in the `sed` command. And since you're forking on bash, you might as well get rid of `xargs` and execute the `ln` inside bash.

Comment: Thanks I believe it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments @gniourf_gniourf. I didn't interpret requirement correctly initially.